# Meaning of $\{a_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ indexed sequence notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have doubts about the notation of sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. If I have a finite set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, does the index sequence notation describe a single possible sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=(1,2,3,4,5)$? Or does this notation describe multiple possible sequences?

Comment: The subscript "$n\in\mathbb{N}$" indicates that the sequence $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ is indexed over the natural numbers. For example, a double sequence would be writen as $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, and this is $\{\dots,a_{-1},a_0,a_1,\dots\}$. I don't know if this answer your question. If not, please elaborate more.

Comment: The standard notation is $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, using parentheses to avoid confusion with sets.

Answer (score 3):

The notation $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ denotes an infinite sequence $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)$, where you have an element $a_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If you're considering this to be a sequence in $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (i.e. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n \in A$), then your sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ could be all sorts of things: $(1,2,1,2,1,2,...)$, $(4,4,4,4,4,4,...)$, $(3,1,4,1,5,2,5,...)$. Importantly, these sequences are all *infinite*, and are not influenced by the structure of the set $A$.

Technically, a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ whose elements are in $A$ is formally defined to be a *function* $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$. The element $a_n$ is the image of $n$ under $f$; that is, $a_n = f(n)$.

My personal preference is actually to not use the notation $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and instead use the notation $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, to emphasize that this is *not* a set: there is an order, and you can repeat elements. You might see people write $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ to indicate that the elements of the sequence are in $A$; this is technically an abuse of notation.

Comment: The notation $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ is fine because it says that the image of $f$ is contained in $A$. But $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq A$ would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this question came to me while reading a property of the $\sigma-algebra$ in measure theory: If $\{E_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of sets in $\Sigma$, then their union is in $\Sigma$. That is $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions. So in this definition there's a problem because the set $\Sigma$ can be finite.